# Django and Mongodb: can't find the django-nonrel for Django 1.9

Tags: mongodb, django-nonrel, django-mongodb-engine

I am a beginner in Django. I'm trying to set up Mongodb with Django 1.9 but I can't find the Django-nonrel version that goes with my Django version.

The only django-nonrel version I find are 1.5 and 1.3, I've found that the last version is "master" but couldn't find any link to install it. Is there any way to install the django-nonrel version for Django 1.9, or is there any other way to setup Mongodb with Django?

Comment: Did you try with djongo? Further info here: https://github.com/nesdis/djongo

Comment: I've tried but it gives me error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'max_name_length'
 any idea why?

Comment: i have used Django 1.11 instead of 1.9 and followed this tutorial http://www.djangocrew.com/blog/mongodb-setup-django-framework/
it worked